# Getting the percentage downloaded from a QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkreply

I'm attempting to get the percentage downloaded from a QNetworkReply as a file is being downloaded by using:

```
connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(getDownloadData(qint64, qint64)) );
```

but when I test my program, I always get:

Progress:
100

which outputs twice and I never get anything below 100. I would like the signal to be emitted every time the download progress changes.

How can I get this to happen? Or have I made a mistake in my code which is preventing it from happening?

EDIT: @dubsjw pointed out that I had a rounding error by using an int. Now I get an increase from 0 to 100 over time for a large image but for a small image, I still only get progress: 0 and progress: 100 with nothing in between. I would like to emit a signal which is received by a progress bar, which smoothly increases from 0 to 100. How can I do this?

filedownloader.h:

```
#ifndef FILEDOWNLOADER_H
#define FILEDOWNLOADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class FileDownloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FileDownloader(QUrl imageUrl, QObject *parent = 0);

    virtual ~FileDownloader();

    QByteArray downloadedData() const;



signals:
        void downloaded();

private slots:

    void fileDownloaded();
   void  getDownloadData(qint64 read, qint64 total);

private:

    QNetworkAccessManager m_WebCtrl;
    QByteArray m_DownloadedData;
    QNetworkReply* reply;

};

#endif // FILEDOWNLOADER_H
```

filedownloader.cpp:

```
#include "filedownloader.h"

FileDownloader::FileDownloader(QUrl imageUrl, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    QNetworkRequest request(imageUrl);
    reply = m_WebCtrl.get(request);

    connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(getDownloadData(qint64, qint64)) );

    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),this, SLOT(fileDownloaded()));


}

FileDownloader::~FileDownloader()
{

}

void FileDownloader::fileDownloaded()
{
    m_DownloadedData = reply->readAll();
    //emit a signal
    reply->deleteLater();
    emit downloaded();
}

QByteArray FileDownloader::downloadedData() const
{
    return m_DownloadedData;
}

 void FileDownloader::getDownloadData(qint64 read, qint64 total)
 {

     qDebug() << "Progress:";
     qint64 percent = (read / total) * 100;
     qDebug() << percent;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your request that you are passing into the get function a valid address?  I would try a debug statement at that point to see if you are getting what you expect.  Also, check to see how many times you the getDownloadData() function is being called. If you see it getting called once with 0 as both the read and total values then you know you don't have a valid request.

Comment: My full program displays an image that has been downloaded. I know it's working because the image is displayed.

Comment: How long does it take for the image to be downloaded, try a larger file size and see if it prints more often and stays at 100.

Comment: I thought it could be because the image size was small but I tried a large image which took around 10 seconds to download. Progress: 0 was printed multiple times and then Progress: 100 was printed once, with nothing in between.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is so that I can then emit a signal which is received by a progress bar, which will show a smooth download from 0% to 100%. But currently it will jump from 0 to 100.

Comment: Is it because you are using an integer and not a float.  Could be rounding it and multiplying by 100, can't believe I didn't notice that before.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't notice that! Now the percentage increases for a large image but it still jumps from 0 to 100 for a small image. How could I get a progress bar to increase from 0 to 100 smoothly for a small image?

Comment: There are many ways you could go about it.  If you really did want to fake it you could have a place holder and as you check the actual download progress increase the number by 1 if the download progress is above that threshold.  That way you would hit every single percentage and it would rise smoothly.